# using tryCatch() in R to assign error values in loop

Tags: r, try-catch

I am struggling with the instructions for tryCatch() in R.  I'm trying to capture the closing price for a ticker.

Case 2 = good case = TickersJuly2 = unique price to ticker relationship

Case 1 = bad case = TickersJuly1 = FABU close price is the repeat of CETX

Case 1 desired output is a 0 for FABU.

```
library(TTR)
close.price1=NULL
TickersJuly1 <- c('DIT','CETX','FABU')
TickersJuly2<- c('AAPL','A','AA')

for(i in TickersJuly1){
           tryCatch(close <- getYahooData(i,20150727,20150727,'daily',"price"),
               error = function(e) close$Close <- 0,
               warning = function(w) close$Close <- 0,
               finally = function(f) close$Close <- 0)
      close.price <- c(as.character(close$Close),i)
      close.price1 <- rbind(close.price1,close.price)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this works.  You should be assigning the result of the `tryCatch` to a variable.

```
for(i in TickersJuly1){
    close <- tryCatch(
        getYahooData(i,20150727,20150727,'daily',"price"),
        error = function(e) list(Close=0),
        warning = function(w) list(Close=0),
        finally = function(f) list(Close=0))
    close.price <- c(as.character(close$Close),i)
    close.price1 <- rbind(close.price1,close.price)
}
```

Comment: The for loop stops after tryCatch assigns close <-0.  You could test this by having TickersJuly1 <- c('DIT',FABU',CETX') . The last ticker will not get evaluated, CETX.

Comment: it does when I run it, I get `            [,1]        [,2]  
close.price "83.540001" "DIT" 
close.price "0"         "FABU"
close.price "2.91"      "CETX"
`